# Combine LIKE and IN on keywords returned from a table

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like

I have a table X with "Description" field. Then, I have another table Y with "Keywords". I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableX
WHERE Description
LIKE IN ('%'||(select keywords from TableY)||'%').
```

Of course, `LIKE IN` is not valid. If I remove the `IN` then I get an error that subquery returned more than one field. Should I be using `regexp_like` for this? If yes, how would the query look like.

Comment: Maybe try doing a join instead of a subselect.  `SELECT... FROM TableX JOIN TableY on TableX.Description like ('%' || TableY.Keyword || '%')`.  The double pipes are allowing you to concatenate the % wildcard before and after the column values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a join like this, but this is likely to be a very slow query in that you will not be able to leverage the use of indexes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableX.*
FROM TableX
INNER JOIN TableY
  ON TableX.Description LIKE (CONCAT('%', TableY.keywords, '%'))
```

You might consider re-visiting your schema if this is a query you expect your application to run regularly.

Comment: I have a very small table , max 2000 rows on which this will run.

Comment: -1 `CONCAT` only accepts two arguments. It would be simpler to use the `||` operator.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp You are correct.  I mostly work in MySQL world where the function takes unlimited arguments.

Comment: This question is tagged for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying for. From my interpretation, something like the following might be close:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] t1
WHERE t1.Description IN
(
  SELECT t2.Description
  FROM [Table2] t2
  WHERE t2.Description LIKE '%&someValue%'
);
```